# Selecting one of two dataframe columns as input into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) which the head looks like:

```
             DATE   BBG  FLAG  DATE_DIFF   NEW_DATE    
0      2014-03-04  1333     1      -31.0 2014-04-03 
1      2014-04-04  1333     0      -91.0 2014-04-04 
2      2014-07-04  1333     1      -31.0 2014-04-07 
3      2014-08-04  1333     1      -31.0 2014-04-08 
4      2014-09-04  1333     1      -30.0 2014-04-09 
5      2014-10-04  1333     1      -31.0 2014-04-10 
6      2014-11-04  1333     1      204.0 2014-04-11
7      2014-04-14  1333     0       -1.0 2014-04-14 
8      2014-04-15  1333     0       -1.0 2014-04-15 
9      2014-04-16  1333     0       -1.0 2014-04-16
```

I am trying to create a new column called `PICKED`, which selects a date from either the `DATE` or `NEW_DATE` column based on the following:

If `FLAG = 1` then if `NEW_DATE` is a valid date then pick `NEW_DATE` otherwise pick DATE.

The expected output will look like:

```
             DATE   BBG   FLAG  DATE_DIFF   NEW_DATE     PICKED
0      2014-03-04  1333      1      -31.0 2014-04-03 2014-04-03
1      2014-04-04  1333      0      -91.0 2014-04-04 2014-04-04
2      2014-07-04  1333      1      -31.0 2014-04-07 2014-04-07
3      2014-08-04  1333      1      -31.0 2014-04-08 2014-04-08
4      2014-09-04  1333      1      -30.0 2014-04-09 2014-04-09
5      2014-10-04  1333      1      -31.0 2014-04-10 2014-04-10
6      2014-11-04  1333      1      204.0 2014-04-11 2014-04-11
7      2014-04-14  1333      0       -1.0 2014-04-14 2014-04-14
8      2014-04-15  1333      0       -1.0 2014-04-15 2014-04-15
9      2014-04-16  1333      0       -1.0 2014-04-16 2014-04-16
```

I am trying to use the following to achive this:

```
df['PICKED'] = np.where(df['FLAG'] == 1, df.NEW_DATE.fillna(df.DATE, inplace=True), df['DATE'])
```

But I get the following returned:

```
             DATE   BBG   FLAG  DATE_DIFF   NEW_DATE     PICKED
0      2014-03-04  1333      1      -31.0 2014-04-03        NaT
1      2014-04-04  1333      0      -91.0 2014-04-04 2014-04-04
2      2014-07-04  1333      1      -31.0 2014-04-07        NaT
3      2014-08-04  1333      1      -31.0 2014-04-08        NaT
4      2014-09-04  1333      1      -30.0 2014-04-09        NaT
5      2014-10-04  1333      1      -31.0 2014-04-10        NaT
6      2014-11-04  1333      1      204.0 2014-04-11        NaT
7      2014-04-14  1333      0       -1.0 2014-04-14 2014-04-14
8      2014-04-15  1333      0       -1.0 2014-04-15 2014-04-15
9      2014-04-16  1333      0       -1.0 2014-04-16 2014-04-16
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were *almost* there. Use -

```
df['PICKED'] = np.where(df['FLAG'] == 1, df.NEW_DATE.fillna(df.DATE), df['DATE'])
```

**Output**

```
    DATE    BBG FLAG    DATE_DIFF   NEW_DATE    PICKED
0   2014-03-04  1333    1   -31.0   2014-04-03  2014-04-03
1   2014-04-04  1333    0   -91.0   2014-04-04  2014-04-04
2   2014-07-04  1333    1   -31.0   2014-04-07  2014-04-07
3   2014-08-04  1333    1   -31.0   2014-04-08  2014-04-08
4   2014-09-04  1333    1   -30.0   2014-04-09  2014-04-09
5   2014-10-04  1333    1   -31.0   2014-04-10  2014-04-10
6   2014-11-04  1333    1   204.0   2014-04-11  2014-04-11
7   2014-04-14  1333    0   -1.0    2014-04-14  2014-04-14
8   2014-04-15  1333    0   -1.0    2014-04-15  2014-04-15
9   2014-04-16  1333    0   -1.0    2014-04-16  2014-04-16
```

**Explanation**

Using the `inplace` parameter modifies the `df` directly. It is great if you use the `fillna()` as you were using in the line before and then use `df.NEW_DATE` directly in `np.where()`

But, the way you are using the `fillna()` needs something to be returned to the `np.where`. Specifying `inplace=True` returns `None` but modifies the `df` directly.

In this case as is evident you needed to return something for the `np.where()` parameter and hence removing the `inplace=True` (which defaults to `inplace=False`) gets you what you need.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation